# How to get total cost of product in mysql from following sql tables?

Tags: mysql, database

How Do i Calculate total cost of product from the following tables?
Table 1: components

```
 pk_comp_id     comp_name           fk_comp_type_id  com_price
        1           Vertical Glass Panels   3               50.00
        2           Side Frame              2               32.00
        3           Front Frame             2               35.00
        4           Roof Section            3               50.00
        5           Door Frame              1               100.00
        6           Standard Timber Plank   2               100.00
        7           Brackets                6               20.00
        8           Door Section            2               50.00
```

Table 2: products

```
 pk_prod_id  prod_name         fk_prod_type_id
    1       Small Green House   1
    2       Large Green House   1
    3       Small Shed          2
    4       Small Summer House  3
    5       Large Summer House  3
```

And Table 3: products_components

```
fk_prod_id  fk_comp_id  number
    1           1       20
    1           2       2
    1           3       2
    1           4       2
    1           5       1
    2           1       40
    2           2       4
    2           3       2
    2           4       4
    2           5       1
    3           6       35
    3           7       60
    3           8       1
```

HERE is what i did so far

```
SELECT 
SUM(`components`.`com_price`*`products_components`.`number`) AS com_g_total,
`products`.`prod_name`, `products`.`pk_prod_id`
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `products_components` ON `products_components`.`fk_prod_id` = `products`.`pk_prod_id`
INNER JOIN `components` ON `components`.`pk_comp_id` = `products_components`.`fk_comp_id`
```

But this gives only one row where as i was suppose to get three row with total cost of each for pk_prod_id 1,2,3.

Comment: You appear to be missing a GROUP BY clause

Comment: And make sure you use a *correct* `group by`: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
SUM(`components`.`com_price`*`products_components`.`number`) AS com_g_total,
`products`.`prod_name`, `products`.`pk_prod_id`
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `products_components` ON `products_components`.`fk_prod_id` = `products`.`pk_prod_id`
INNER JOIN `components` ON `components`.`pk_comp_id` = `products_components`.`fk_comp_id`
GROUP BY `products`.`pk_prod_id`
```

Result:

```
COM_G_TOTAL   PROD_NAME            PK_PROD_ID
1334          Small Green House    1
2498          Large Green House    2
4750          Small Shed           3
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb899/2).

Comment: I did the same but did not somehow work that time but now its working. Thanks Raging